# flyway schema giving IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, flyway

On running flyway schema I'm receiving this exception.using Java 8 with spring boot.

Flyway is not able to initialize.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.flywaydb.core.api.MigrationType.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.flywaydb.core.api.MigrationType.
```

Comment: Which version of flyway are you using ? Also are you sure that the error message is complete, there should be an enum constant name after `org.flywaydb.core.api.MigrationType.` .

Comment: @Arnaud I'm using Flyway Community Edition 5.0.6 by Boxfuse.

Comment: Exception I've attached is  intial part of error.

Comment: These are my flyway properties in properties file

flyway.enabled=true
flyway.locations=classpath:db/base,classpath:db/starzplay
flyway.placeholder-replacement=false

Comment: Those links may be related : https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2328 and https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2126

Comment: Thanks @Arnaud , but I'm unable to find related solution there can you please explain it for me if you know the reason I can only see the problem and related link mentioned there.

Comment: Do I need to upgrade flyway version?

Comment: @Arnaud can you please have a look at issue again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `flyway_schema_history` table, there you will see that you have an entry with `installed_rank` value set to 0, delete the row and run your application again. This will sort the issue out.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following :
DELETE FROM flyway_schema_history WHERE TYPE = 'DELETE'